# complex condition in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, conditional-statements

How do I do this in a django template:

```
{% if li_status.profile_exists and (op1.conns|length > 0 or op2.conns|length > 0) %}
```

Parentheses are illegal in this expression and I'm not sure how the expression will be evaluated without them.

I prefer to do this in a single line and not using a nested if

Comment: perhaps you can move conditions to a server side property ( or custom method )

Comment: Its not possible in single block. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`

Answer (score 2):

As danihp said, there's often no reason to do such a thing in a template.
This kind of logic should be avoided in templates, that's why Django does not provide the ability to do that.

Did you try something like this in your view?

```
def your_view(request):

    # Stuff
    condition = li_status.profile_exists and (len(op1.conns) > 0 or len(op2.conns) > 0)

    return render_to_response('your-template.html',
    {
        'condition': condition 
    },
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if condition %}
...
```

Comment: Ok, but what if the condition is in a loop, and operates on properties of a items within that queryset?

Comment: I agree with you @BenDavis, this could be a nice addon to Django templating

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is in a loop, and operates on properties of items within that queryset (as per Ben Davis' comment), then the technique is to run the loop *and decorate it* before you put the result in the context. Below is one of many ways to do this:

```python
# in the view somewhere
qs = MyObject.objects.all()
decorated = []
for item in qs:
    item.field_that_does_not_exist_on_the_model = expensive(item)
    decorated.append(item)
```

.. then you put `decorated` in the context, not the `qs` and use t like any other field:

```
{% for item in decorated %}
    {% if item.field_that_does_not_exist_on_the_model %}
    ..
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another bonus of doing it this way that if it is slow as heck, *it is **possible** to optimize it*. You cannot optimize queryset access after the queryset has been handed over to the template.